# Iterating an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a data-structure where i have an array inside an array which i need to iterate and compare. **I need to compare my `datasets` array with `patientList` array whether they both have same `id's`**

My **DS**:

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f6e6d39a31fb5419c7b587"),
        "datasets" : [
                ObjectId("55f6c34e9e3cdc00273b57a3"),
                ObjectId("55f6c3569e3cdc00273b57a4"),
                ObjectId("55f6c3639e3cdc00273b57a5"),
                ObjectId("55f6c36e9e3cdc00273b57a6"),
                ObjectId("55f6c3789e3cdc00273b57a7")
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f6e6d39a31fb5419c7b587"),
        "datasets" : [
                ObjectId("55f6c34e9e3cdc00273b57a3"),
                ObjectId("55f6c3569e3cdc00273b57a4"),
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
];
```

Code:

```
if ($scope.data.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < $scope.data[i].datasets; j++) {
            if ($scope.data[i].datasets[j] == $scope.patientList[i]._id) {
                $scope.data[i].datasets[j].push($scope.patientList[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$scope.patientList` is an array of objects having `_id` and `patientname`. The above code is not working.

Comment: You are modifying your array while you iterate it, using the array's length as your upper limit.  Are you really sure you want to do that?

Comment: @DavidL: I knoew i can keep a new array, but the above code when i am trying to iterate is not working... not sure where its going wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you expect it to that it is not currently doing?

Comment: I want to compare the datasets array with another array... to see if they both have same id's.

Comment: I'm still incredibly confused.  What do you want to do if they DO have the same IDs?  Do you want to grab duplicates?  Do you want to remove non-matches?  Do you want to move matches to a new array?  It's very difficult to understand what you really want to do here.

Comment: Do you want to move matches to a new array? Yes...

Comment: then why are you pushing matches to the same array if you want them in a new array?

Comment: You didn't include `$scope.patientList`, so the question is incomplete and unanswerable.  Please update the question with a small, complete, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

```
j < $scope.data[i].datasets
```

Wasn't the limit supposed to be a numeric value, instead of a container?

I guess you want it to be `j < $scope.date[i].datasets.length` as well...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it will work if you put `$scope.data[i].datasets.length.`